# When to put on Shabbos clothes

Tags: shabbat, clothing, erev-shabbat

Can someone tell me a source which says one is supposed to put on Shabbos clothes no earlier than Mincha Ketanah on Friday?   Or is there any source which addresses when to put on Shabbos clothes on Friday?

Comment: 262:3 https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A8%D7%A1%D7%91_%D7%92

Answer (score 3):

As far as this:

> Or is there any source which addresses when to put on Shabbos clothes on Friday?

It is worth noting the breakdown [here](https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/chapter-1-the-shabbos-preparations/) based on the Shulchan Aruch HaRav

> **When on Erev Shabbos should one put on his Shabbos clothes:**<sup>1</sup> It is proper<sup>2</sup> that one garb himself in Shabbos clothes immediately after bathing himself for Shabbos. For this reason, it is proper<sup>3</sup> for one to bathe himself as close to Shabbos as possible<sup>4</sup>, and then immediately put on his Shabbos clothes.<sup>5</sup> [This however only applies when bathing in one’s home. If however one is bathing in a bathhouse, as is customary when going to Mikveh on Erev Shabbos, then one should visit the Mikveh with plenty of time still left in the day.<sup>6</sup> If one however plans to merely [rinse and then] immerse in the Mikveh, he is to visit the Mikveh as close to Shabbos as possible.<sup>7</sup>

---

> <sup>1</sup> [262:5](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3447044/jewish/Shulchan-Aruch-Chapter-262-To-Sanctify-Shabbos-by-Preparing-Ones-Table-and-Wearing-Clean-Garments.htm#v5)
>
> <sup>2</sup> Lit. good
>
> <sup>3</sup> Lit. good
>
> <sup>4</sup> Lit. near sunset.
>
> <sup>5</sup> This is done in order so one only begins dressing himself in Shabbos clothes in close proximity to Shabbos. The advantage of doing so is that it is now apparent that it is in honor of Shabbos that one is wearing them. [ibid]
>
> <sup>6</sup> As we suspect he may come to take his time and come to transgress Shabbos.
>
> <sup>7</sup> [Ketzos Hashulchan 73 footnote 23](https://beta.otzar.org/#/book/150742/p/34/t/0.43486613306865011234/fs/0/start/0/end/0/c)